# Manchester encoding and collision detection on Ethernet

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols, ethernet

I'm reading a book about networks and it makes the comment that Ethernet uses Manchester encoding and that, if two hosts are not perfectly in synch with each other, that this allows for early collision detection.  It doesn't explain why however and I am wondering if someone can clarify this for me.

Regards.

Comment: do you want clarification on syncing or on collision detection? I am asking this because the wiki page on manchester coding describes the reason for syncing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code

Comment: I am asking about collision detection.  The book I am reading does not go into any details about how this is done and Googling the topic has turned up very little.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you read the wiki article on CSMACD which is what ethernet uses.  It explains how the collision detection algorithm works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection

This of course is less of an issue now with switched networks but was useful in the "old days" of bus style cable ethernet or hub based broadcast ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for syncing can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code.

The answer for collision detection can be found here. http://www.google.com/patents/US5012467.
It is link to an US Patent but its abstract describes why  collision detection is possible with manchester encoding.